# selectedIndex is returning "undefined" as value

Tags: javascript

Forgive me if this is a stupid question; it's been many years since I've worked with javascript. This is actually javascript and html rendered via PHP in Joomla, but I've tried using the same code in a plain old local HTML file and I'm getting the same error. I have a select field with several options, and onchange I want to set the value of a text field to the value of the selected option. No matter which option I choose, the text field is being set to "undefined". Can anyone help me out? Here's the plain html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setPrefix(){
    var f = document.adminForm;
    f.prefix.value = f.editprefixes.selectedIndex.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="adminForm">

<select name="editprefixes" onchange="javascript:setPrefix()">
<option value=1000>1000</option>
<option value=1001>1001</option>
<option value=1005>1005</option>
<option value=1011>1011</option>
<option value=1016>1016</option>
</select>
<br />

<input type="text" name="prefix" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also there isn't really a reason to prefix javascript code in an attribute with the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol. `onchange="setPrefix()"` will work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `<select>`'s `selectedIndex` property does not refer to an actual `<option>` object, but rather is an integer corresponding to the index of the option that is selected (so the first option is 0, second is 1, and so on).

If you want to get the value of the selected option, you need to use:

```
var sel = f.editprefixes;
f.prefix.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: +1, a good explanation.  FWIW, `sel.value` would also work for this scenario in all browsers.

Comment: This still only returns the entire `select` tag for me, not the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f.prefix.value = f.editprefixes.options[f.editprefixes.selectedIndex].value;
```